# Angular how to display number always with 4 decimal places in <input>

Tags: angularjs

I have a float value for the ng-model that I would like to always display with 4 decimal places in the  `<input>:`

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal"  ng-model="myDecimal | number : 4"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-currency` to handle decimal points. You can use fraction to determine the number of decimal places. By default it is 2.

For more details [ng-currency](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ng-currency']);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
  $scope.amount = 0.431264;
});
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-currency/1.2.3/ng-currency.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
          <div class="row">
            <input type="text" 
                   ng-model="amount"
                   currency-symbol=""
                   ng-currency 
                   fraction="4" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **value** attribute of input type.

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal"  ng-model="myDecimal" value="myDecimal | number : 4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because of *nonAssign* error. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign).

You can use the curly braces notation to truncate the decimals.
`{{ myDecimal | number: 4 }}`

Please note that the *number* filter does not really truncate the decimal places but rounds-off the number to those many decimal places.

In short, you cannot use `type=number` and a filter in `ng-model` as per the code you have shared.

If you necessarily have to use the number type, then I would suggest to round off the value before putting it in the input box.